# Accessing model has_many property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models:

```
Post.rb 
   has_many :likes
   belongs_to :user

Like.rb
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :post

User.rb
   has_many :posts
   has_many :likes
```

I'm trying to query the user likes in the view like this:

```
<% @user.likes.each do |i| %>
    <%= i.post.title %>
<% end %>
```

and it returns undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass

I only can reach the array of posts like this:

```
<% @user.likes.each do |i| %>
    <%= i.post %>
<% end %>
```

Or like this `<%= @user.likes.first.post.title %>`

I can't understand why I can't reach the "title" or any other property.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems at least one of `@user.likes` doesn't have its associated post. So `Like#post` returns `nil`, and on that `nil` object you try to call `title` which raises an error. If this situation is not desired, you probably have to validate likes so that every `Like` has its `post`:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validate :post, presence: true
```

if so, you probably should also make sure associated likes are destroyed when the post is destroyed:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
```

You also can fetch likes only with associated post like this:

```
<% @user.likes.joins(:post).each do |i| %>
```

or use [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) in view, so that when like without post is reached, no error is raised:

```
<%= i.post.try(:title) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your like always belongs to post, it would be better to have user association with **likes** using "through: :posts" option. That is correct way of association in this scenario.

So your code will be as follows:

```
Post.rb 
   has_many :likes
   belongs_to :user

Like.rb
   belongs_to :post

User.rb
   has_many :posts
   has_many :likes, through: :posts
```

and then you can access user's likes as:

```
<% @user.likes.each do |i| %>
  <%= i.post.title %>
<% end %>
```

Which will always contain post title.